# How to create a good WebSite/WebApp

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am willing at creating a website offering some kind of service to end users. The user can thus search according to different parameters. The search is done on a database. Then, the results are printed. The user can also login, and post some offers.

First, is it possible to do this with a classic CMS (wordpress, joomla,..). 
I was adviced to this using asp.net, what do you think ? 
Or will I need to create the website (pages) on one side, and the web app on another ?

Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using WordPress. The CMS makes it easy to create users who can write/edit/contribute to posts based on their permissions. WordPress also has a lot of [tutorials](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/) on-line and [themes](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress) are available to make things even easier. As for searching there is the built in function or multiple plugins available that will be easy to set up.

Comment: Thannk you for your answer. Is it possible in wordpress to implement a web application behind the website, in C# for instance ?

Comment: Not within Wordpress itself. Wordpress is built in PHP but if you created the web app in a different domain it would be possible to include it on the site, If you needed to use asp.net and c# maybe [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DNN ( dot net nuke) for you requirement or else use UMBRACO if you know MVC well.